# Isekai web novel where the main character eventually starts killing golden rabbits to level up

Tags: story-identification, novel

All I remember is in this list:

1. transported to another world
2. starts in a forest
3. fights rabbits
4. kills bandits
5. goes to village and stays at an inn
6. travels to a town that has 3 different forest nearby a C rank forest with orcs, a B rank
   forest with cockatrice, and a A rank forest with giants (I think)
7. he eventually starts killing golden rabbits to level up as they give a lot more exp.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.